# Unable to parse JSON file in obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, nsjsonserialization

**I am unable to parse the following JSON file. It's giving `the operation couldn’t be completed. (cocoa error 3840.)`.

Here is my code:

```
- (NSString *)loadJsFromFile:(NSString *)fileName
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString *jsScript = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    return jsScript;
} 

//

 NSString *strInputParam = [self loadJsFromFile:@"samplein"];

 NSData *dataInput = [strInputParam dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 NSError *error;

 NSObject *input = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataInput options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

 if(error)
 {
    NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
 }
```

I have also tried the following, but it didn't help, pls help me out to parse this JSON. Thanx in advance.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"samplein" ofType:@"txt"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSError *error;

NSObject *input = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataInput options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

if(error)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
}
```

this is my JSON data

```
sampleinputdata = {
        "round": {
            "id" : 1,
            "course" : {
                "id" : 2,
                "slope" : 118,
                "holes" : [ {
                    "id" : 1,
                    "hole_number" : 1,
                    "handicap" : 5,
                    "par" : 4
                } , {
                    "id" : 2,
                    "hole_number" : 2,
                    "handicap" : 7,
                    "par" : 3
                } , {
                    "id" : 3,
                    "hole_number" : 3,
                    "handicap" : 8,
                    "par" : 3
                } , {
                    "id" : 4,
                    "hole_number" : 4,
                    "handicap" : 10,
                    "par" : 4
                }, {
                    "id" : 4,
                    "hole_number" : 5,
                    "handicap" : 10,
                    "par" : 4
                } , {
                    "id" : 5,
                    "hole_number" : 6,
                    "handicap" : 10,
                    "par" : 4
                } , {
                    "id" : 6,
                    "hole_number" : 7,
                    "handicap" : 10,
                    "par" : 4
                } , {
                    "id" : 7,
                    "hole_number" : 8,
                    "handicap" : 9,
                    "par" : 5
                } , {
                    "id" : 8,
                    "hole_number": 9,
                    "handicap" : 11,
                    "par" : 3
                } , {
                    "id" : 9,
                    "hole_number" : 10,
                    "handicap" : 5,
                    "par" : 4
                } , {
                    "id" : 10,
                    "hole_number" : 11,
                    "handicap" : 7,
                    "par" : 3
                } , {
                    "id" : 11,
                    "hole_number" : 12,
                    "handicap" : 8,
                    "par" : 3
                } , {
                    "id" : 12,
                    "hole_number" : 13,
                    "handicap" : 10,
                    "par" : 4
                }, {
                    "id" : 13,
                    "hole_number" : 14,
                    "handicap" : 10,
                    "par" : 4
                } , {
                    "id" : 14,
                    "hole_number" : 15,
                    "handicap" : 10,
                    "par" : 4
                } , {
                    "id" : 15,
                    "hole_number" : 16,
                    "handicap" : 10,
                    "par" : 4
                } , {
                    "id" : 16,
                    "hole_number" : 17,
                    "handicap" : 10,
                    "par" : 4
                } , {
                    "id" : 17,
                    "hole_number" : 18,
                    "handicap" : 9,
                    "par" : 5
                } ]
            },
            "viewer" : [
                {
                    "id" : 1,
                    "name" : "jimmy dean",
                    "handicap" : 10,
                    "n_flag" : true,
                    "g_flag" : true,
                    "group_name" : "groupone",
                    "team_name" : "teamtwo",
                    "scores" : [1,4,1,5,3,2,4,3,2,5,2,4,4,4,4,5,3,2]
                } , {
                    "id" : 2,
                    "name" : "martha s",
                    "handicap" : 12,
                    "n_flag" : true,
                    "g_flag" : true,
                    "group_name" : "groupone",
                    "team_name" : "teamtwo",
                    "scores" : [3,4,6,5,3,2,4,3,2,5,2,1,4,4,4,5,3,2]
                } , {
                    "id" : 3,
                    "name" : "jim bob",
                    "handicap" : 11,
                    "n_flag" : true,
                    "g_flag" : true,
                    "group_name" : "groupone",
                    "team_name" : "teamone",
                    "scores" : [3,4,6,5,3,2,4,3,2,5,2,4,6,4,4,5,3,2]
                } , {
                    "id" : 4,
                    "name" : "big mac",
                    "handicap" : 13,
                    "n_flag" : true,
                    "g_flag" : true,
                    "group_name" : "groupone",
                    "team_name" : "teamone",
                    "scores" : [3,4,6,5,3,2,4,3,2,5,2,4,4,4,4,2,3,2]
                }
            ],
            "bets" : {
                "net_skins_bet": 10.00,
                "gross_skins_bet": 5.00,
                "better_ball_bet": 10.00,
                "nassau_bets" : [
                    {
                        "id" : 1,
                        "min_golfer_id" : 2,
                        "max_golfer_id" : 3,
                        "bet_amount" : 10.00
                    } , {
                        "id" : 2,
                        "min_golfer_id" : 2,
                        "max_golfer_id" : 4,
                        "bet_amount" : 10.00
                    } , {
                        "id" : 3,
                        "min_golfer_id" : 3,
                        "max_golfer_id" : 4,
                        "bet_amount" : 10.00
                    } , {
                        "id" : 4,
                        "min_golfer_id" : 1,
                        "max_golfer_id" : 2,
                        "bet_amount" : 12.00
                    } , {
                        "id" : 5,
                        "min_golfer_id" : 1,
                        "max_golfer_id" : 3,
                        "bet_amount" : 5.00
                    } , {
                        "id" : 6,
                        "min_golfer_id" : 1,
                        "max_golfer_id" : 4,
                        "bet_amount" : 0.00
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please paste your method loadJsFromFile. Also if you begin your JSON with sampleinputdata = {, then it is not valid JSON.

Comment: `0|1|2` == a bit nasty. But the 2nd code snippet should work for valid JSON data.

Comment: Why do people think JSON should be converted to an NSString? NSJSONSerialization has a perfectly fine method to create JSON from a URL, including a file URL.

Comment: Please fix the formatting.

Comment: @TomErikStøwer i have tried to parse that JSON data using this online parser http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/  and it parsed successfully

Comment: Then you have not used the same JSON as you have posted here. I just tried and it did not pass.

Comment: Since this is a .txt file, what are the odds that someone created it with a stupid Windows editor that puts BOMs at the start of the file? And the two stars at the end make it invalid as well. I'd print out the first ten bytes of the NSData and see what is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several apparent problems here:

<del>1. You have not posted the code from this method (```loadJsFromFile:```), so there could be something wrong there that we can't comment on.

    ```NSString *strInputParam = [self loadJsFromFile:@"samplein.txt"];```</del>

<del>2. What is the intention of these options? 0|1|2?

    ```NSObject *input = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataInput options:0|1|2 error:&error];```</del>

According to http://jsonlint.com/, your JSON is not valid:

`Parse error on line 1:
    sampleinputdata={

    ^
    Expecting '{', '['`

Hence,

`sampleinputdata = { ... }` is not valid JSON. Perhaps you meant `"sampleinputdata": { ... }`, or simply `{ ... }`.

Note: There's no need to pass the data through a string, you can load it directly from file to NSData. So your second method is the one you should use.

Comment: I have looked at it. Your JSON is still not valid.

Comment: i have tried to parse that JSON data using this online parser http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and it parsed successfully

Comment: I am using the same JSON which i have posted, i guess u might have copied those ** which is there in the end

Comment: You also have to remove the initial "sampleinputdata = ". I just tested this in Xcode now. When leaving "sampleinputdata = ", I get the error you got, as expected. When removing it, no errors.

Comment: Thank you,,it worked out,,,but how can http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ could able to parse it?  though it is invalid

Comment: I can't really answer that. Their parser evidently accepts a more lenient syntax than the standard JSON specificiation. For the future, you might want to pay more attention to what people are trying to tell you the answer is, rather than insisting on otherwise.